# Registering more than one script depend on jquery to wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
function twentythirteen_scripts_styles()
{

... // Other code

// Load the Omedia's CSS files
wp_enqueue_style('css-bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.0.2');
wp_enqueue_style('css-index', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/index.css', array(), '1.1');
wp_enqueue_style('css-kbc-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/kbc-styles.css', array(), '1.0');
wp_enqueue_style('css-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/menu.css', array(), '1.0');
wp_enqueue_style('css-rating', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/rating.css', array(), '1.0');

// Load the Omedia's JS files
wp_enqueue_script('js-bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '2013-11-14', true);
wp_enqueue_script('js-index', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/index.js', array('jquery'), '2013-11-14', true);
wp_enqueue_script('js-kbcdeli', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/kbcdeli.js', array('jquery'), '2013-11-20', true);
wp_enqueue_script('js-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', array('jquery'), '2013-11-20', true);
wp_enqueue_script('js-nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nav.js', array('jquery'), '2013-11-20', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentythirteen_scripts_styles');
```

Here is my code of registering scripts and styles in `functions.php` (I altered the original file of twentythirteen theme). I have 4 manual scripts file `(index.js, kbcdeli.js, menu.js, nav.js)`. I test my theme on browsers, 4 files are loaded but only `index.js` can execute its script.

Someone help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the answer for my question. All my jquery code have to be wrapped by

```
(function ($) {
...
})(jQuery);
```

Just that, everything will be alright! Can someone explain to me the reason why I have to do so? Why not:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
...
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function ($) {
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 4 files are loaded , and you can see and read them in source ( not missing ) for example with firebug or going directly to the URL - then there is a different problem regarding to those scripts .

Without further info , It is very difficult to pinpoint , but as for your direct question and the function you posted for loading the scripts there are no problems and the function itself is fine .

( the only thing I would advise is to change the version to something like `20131120` without dashes - but I assume it will have little effect - although  I remember one time to have a problem with loading scripts caused by letters in the version .. but I could not later reproduce it )

Also - do you have `wp_footer()` and `wp_head` in the theme ? ( I assume yes if you see them printed - but just in case .. )

Comment: Thank for your answer! I tried to remove the dashes but they have not worked yet. I also have `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in my template file. But I've just found one thing strange: when I test the homepage `http://kbcdeli.com/`, everything is good, those scripts work fine. But if test a subpage such as `http://kbcdeli.com/thuc-don/`, the above problem appears! I have no idea what is happening!!?!